# Issue with my Ubuntu Apache Conf file. (Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.)

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, ubuntu, virtual-machine

This below is the conf file for https://github.com/treeio/treeio
I used this method: http://goo.gl/KTdlUT , to configure treeio to my Azure Based Ubuntu VM but still it says: Forbidden  You don't have permission to access / on this server.)

```
<virtualhost *:80>

ServerAdmin abcd@xyz.com

ServerName abcd.net

ServerAlias abcd.net

DocumentRoot "/home/User/treeio"

<Directory /home/Userk/treeio/>

<Directory /home/User/treeio/>

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess treeio.djangoserver processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GRO$
WSGIProcessGroup treeio.djangoserver
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/User/treeio/wsgi
ErrorLog  "/home/User/treeio/log/error.log"

CustomLog "/home/User/treeio/log/access.log" combined

</virtualhost>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some configurations prefer Django projects to be installed in the **/var/www/** directory, even though up until now the home folder had been the recommended location.  This seems to make sense from a security perspective.

In addition, Microsoft has the simplest step-by-step instructions which actually work with Unbunto 14.04 in Azure:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-python-django-web-app-linux/